# APK isn't installing on single devices

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I have a problem is with installing my application on random devices. The app works on my phone (Android 6.0) and on emulator (7.1.1), but it can't be installed on friends' phones with e.g. same Android version or 5.0 probably. Is there any IDE-side reason (IntelliJ IDEA, earlier Android Studio with same error)?
There is fragment of `build.gradle` in my project. Maybe it'll help somehow...

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pkgname"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "Pre-release"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
    pre_release {
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you make debug-version your .apk. Look at - https://techtuts.info/2014/05/build-release-apk-android-studio/

Comment: So changing build type to e.g. `release` should fix the problem? (I'll check it anyway)

Comment: I had the same problem (my application did not start with friends), and I fixed it with the help of the release version.

Answer (score 1):

Will you please let us know whether you're trying to use the build apk generated at the time of installing app directly to your know or you are creating a fresh build.

**Note: if you want to support all devices as per your build config then you must have you create a clean build and then try to install app within your required devices.Hope it will help.**

Comment: The problem was with build type. I've generated signed APK by IDE, but as 'debug' build type. That was causing an error.